# How to get the value of the least and most expensive book in sql?

Tags: sql, group-by, sqlplus

How to get the value of the least and the most expensive book for each publisher that is based on the retail price?

I have already queried the tables below. However I just don't know how to get, which I thought would be the last 5 rows, the result for this one. Also, if I understood the question right.

```
select name, title, retail, sum(quantity)
from books full outer join orderitems using(isbn)
join publisher using(pubid)
group by name, title, retail
order by retail;

NAME                    TITLE                              RETAIL SUM(QUANTITY)
----------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -------------
REED-N-RITE             BIG BEAR AND LITTLE DOVE             8.95             4
READING MATERIALS INC.  COOKING WITH MUSHROOMS              19.95             8
PRINTING IS US          REVENGE OF MICKEY                      22             5
AMERICAN PUBLISHING     HANDCRANKED COMPUTERS                  25             2
READING MATERIALS INC.  THE WOK WAY TO COOK                 28.75
READING MATERIALS INC.  HOW TO GET FASTER PIZZA             29.95
READING MATERIALS INC.  BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY       30.95             1
PRINTING IS US          HOW TO MANAGE THE MANAGER           31.95             1
REED-N-RITE             SHORTEST POEMS                      39.95             1
PUBLISH OUR WAY         E-BUSINESS THE EASY WAY              54.5             2
AMERICAN PUBLISHING     DATABASE IMPLEMENTATION             55.95             7
PUBLISH OUR WAY         BUILDING A CAR WITH TOOTHPICKS      59.95
AMERICAN PUBLISHING     HOLY GRAIL OF ORACLE                75.95             3
REED-N-RITE             PAINLESS CHILD-REARING              89.95             6
```

Comment: min(), max(), group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hard to tell as you haven't shown us the other tables, but how about:

```
select publisher, min(retail), max(retail)
from books join orderitems using(isbn)
join publisher using(pubid)
group by publisher;
```

Key points:

- You want a min and a max **per publisher** so group by the publisher
- `min(retail)` gives you the minimum value of `retail` for all books in the group (the publisher) so that tells you the cheapest book each publisher publishes.
- Similarly, `max` tells you the most expensive

Comment: Thanks again! At first I was getting the wrong query, but this helped. I overthought about it and made it complicated hehe. I appreciate the help :)